# How can I execute both commands in an sh file?

Tags: shell

I have created an sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/try.py
sudo matchbox-keyboard
```

and when I execute the file, the program: try.py runs but the matchbox keyboard does not appear. Only when I close the program will the matchbox keyboard will appear. I want them to both appear at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script executes both commands sequentially and waits each time until the command returns.

You could change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/try.py &
sudo matchbox-keyboard
```

Comment: Thank you @Max I have tried sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/try.py && sudo matchbox-keyboard but it didn't work. I should have just added one ampersand! Thanks